# At unique critical point, does local max imply global max?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with continuous derivative. Suppose $f$ has a unique critical point $x_0\in (a,b)$. If $f$ has a local maximum at $x_0$, then $f$ must have a global maximum at $x_0$. Intuitively, if $f$ had a global maximum somewhere else, the graph would have to turn around, leading to a second critical point.

I would like to know if a similar results holds in two dimensions.

> Does there exist a connected open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and a function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ with continuous first partial derivatives, such that $f$ has a unique critical point $u_0\in U$, which is a local maximum but not a global maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, see example below.  The question arises due to the phenomenon that a real valued differentiable function $f$  (defined on an interval) which has only one critical point in which it possesses a maximum that maximum must be global. (It may have some other critical points as well.)

Take $f(x,y)=-x^3-y^2+xy$, defined on $\mathbb R^2$ without the negative $x$-axis, for example.  The domain is simply connected.  Now the only maximum $f$ has is in  $ (1/6, 1/12)$, obviously not a global one.

[image]

The behaviour of $f$ becomes clearer if we write $f$f as
$$f(x,y)=x^3+\frac14x^2+(y-x/2)^2.$$
This shows that $f$ is a parabolic transformation surface.

Comment: You should mention what $U$ is: a connected open set that contains $(1/6, 1/12)$ and, say, $(-1,-1/2)$, but not $(0,0)$...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks, corrected.